# Getting "method saveas of object _workbook failed" error while trying to save an XLS as CSV

Tags: excel, vba, csv, runtime-error, save-as

I have a weird problem.
I have a piece of VBA code that works perfectly fine. Many of my colleagues use it to create CSV files without problems.

```
    Sub CSV_Tagetik()

    Dim newWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim vWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim vWorkbook As String
    Dim vEntity
    Dim vDate As String
    
    

    vWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    
    '--------------TGK------------
    
        vEntity = Worksheets("Control").Cells(6, 3)
        vRange = Worksheets("Control").Cells(1, 18)
        vDate = Worksheets("Control").Cells(4, 3)
        
        Sheets("Journaalpost").Visible = True
        Sheets("Journaalpost").Select
        
        ActiveSheet.Range(vRange).AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<>0", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
        
        Range(vRange).Select
        Selection.Copy
        
        Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
        newWorkbook.Activate
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        
        newWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = vEntity
        
        newWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Workbooks(vWorkbook).Path & "\" & vEntity & " Aansluiting Tagetik " & vDate, FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
        CreateBackup:=False

      
        newWorkbook.Close
        Sheets("Journaalpost").Visible = False
        Sheets("Control").Select
        
        
Finally:

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
      
   
  
  
    
    Exit Sub
    
End Sub
```

But now there is a new colleague for whom the save command

```
newWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Workbooks(vWorkbook).Path & "\" & vEntity & " Aansluiting Tagetik " & vDate, FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
            CreateBackup:=False
```

prompts an error:
Run-time error '1004':
Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Worksheet' failed

I have no idea why. I cannot recreate it in my environment, because for me it works perfectly.

What steps could I take to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Assuming `vDate` actually is a date, you probably need to format it so that it doesn't have invalid filename characters in it (like slashes).

Comment: thank you, I'll check if her date formatting is different in any way. should be dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: Use `& Format(vDate,"dd-mm-yyyy")` and the user's setting won't matter.

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you! solved :)